# Hardware supported mutual exclusion

Tags: operating-system

I'm currently taking a class in Operating Systems, and everything has been smooth until I encountered Concurrency and Mutual Exclusion.

Up until this chapter in the text I am currently reading, I was under the impression that the OS handled calls to certain I/O operations such as printers through queues and interrupts, and the OS also handled the scheduling of processes.

But in this section "Mutual exclusion: Hardware support", it states for a process to guarantee mutual exclusion it is sufficient to block all interrupts, and this can be done through interrupt disabling, however the cost is high since the processor is limited in its ability to interleave(Stallings, p. 211).

If this is a capability, whats stopping a programmer from placing his entire program within a critical section by disabling interrupts? And why can't the OS handle calls to critical resources, in the way that was previously stated(I/O queues & interrupts), but we must rely on programmers to identify their critical sections?

I understand the need for to identify critical sections with shared variables and memory space, but I am baffled as to why a program needs to identify its critical section with regard to I/O devices such as a printers and why the OS can't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not [entirely] correct:

> But in this section "Mutual exclusion: Hardware support", it states for a process to guarantee mutual exclusion it is sufficient to block all interrupts, and this can be done through interrupt disabling, however the cost is high since the processor is limited in its ability to interleave.

Processors generally support multiple means of synchronization. The simplest is uninterruptible instructions. These will be generally be short instructions such as set a bit or branch if the bit was set already. Such instructions allow synchronization within a single processor.

As you mention, disabling interrupts is another method. Generally, interrupts have priorities. Usually you can disable all interrupts that has a priority lower than specified. That allows disabling all or some interrupts.

Disabling interrupts only works when locking resources that are not shared by multiple processors.

That is why the quote you have in the context you have it is not [entirely] correct. Disabling interrupts on a processor does not synchronize when there are multiple processors. However, in theory, an operating system could disable all interrupts on all processors but such system would be seriously brain damaged because that would hamper the performance of a multi-processor system. But that might work in, say, a quick-and-dirty student project operating system.

> If this is a capability, whats stopping a programmer from placing his entire program within a critical section by disabling interrupts?

Disabling interrupts is only possible in kernel mode.

Another method of hardware synchronization is interlocked instructions. These are instructions that lock the memory of the operands and prevent other processors from accessing that memory while the instruction is executing. Sometimes are are simple add integer interlocked and bit set (or clear) and branch interlocked instructions.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Also the author does mention that this would only work in uniprocessor system. But if you can also help me clear something up, if we did use interrupt disabling, in a uniprocessor system to handle 2 different programs making use of a printer, how would this work? Would it be a module (Linux kernel) that handles printing calls to the OS disables interrupts while it prepares the printer and the file to be printed?

Comment: Disabling interrupts to synchronize the use of a printer would not work. You would have interrupts disabled way to long. Typically an operating system architecture document would say how many instructions may be executed while interrupts are disabled. For a printer or file you need a different type of locking system.

Comment: Awesome, Thank you!